# Why does transaction.wasCommitted() return false?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jakarta-ee, glassfish

I am new to hibernate and java-ee in general and I was wondering if anyone could tell me why this piece of code returns false even though from looking at the database I can see the transaction was actually committed:

```
    session.beginTransaction();
    session.saveOrUpdate(user);
    session.getTransaction().commit();
    return session.getTransaction().wasCommitted(); //Always false
```

Thanks!

Comment: From the API javadoc: `Check if this transaction was successfully committed.
This method could return false even after successful invocation of commit(). As an example, JTA based strategies no-op on commit() calls if they did not start the transaction; in that case, they also report wasCommitted() as false.` Dunno if that explains anything.

Comment: Because the commit has not necessarily happened just after you ask for it (maybe commit() is launched in another thread), etc... Anyway makes no sense to ask for something you just did (this is like asking if a == 3 after doing a = 2 + 1).

Comment: Well that is odd, why have a method that doesn't really work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`wasCommitted()` need not always return `true` even if the commit was **successful**. It'll return `true` if the transaction was (unequivocally) `committed` via this local transaction; `false` otherwise.

From the [docs](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.2/api/org/hibernate/Transaction.html#wasCommitted()):-

> **wasCommitted**
>
> This method could return false even after successful invocation of
> commit(). As an example, JTA based strategies no-op on commit() calls
> if they did not start the transaction; in that case, they also report
> wasCommitted() as false.