# Check if transaction in hibernate successful

Tags: java, hibernate, transactions, try-catch

I am developing an application using hibernate and I save `Entities` as usual inside `hibernate` transactions. I want to 'get Feedback' from a transaction if it has completed sucessfully or not and according to that to excecute next code. Here is the trivial method I use to update the entity:

```
public boolean updateDepartment(Department s) {
        Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
        Transaction tx = HibernateUtil.getTransaction(session);
        boolean success = false;
        try 
        {
            tx.begin();
            session.update(s);
            tx.commit();
            success = true;
        } 
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            tx.rollback();
            e.printStackTrace();
            success = false;
        }

        return success;
    }
```

Invocation of the method from other code:

```
boolean b = dao.updateDepartment(d);
if(b)
{
 doStuff();
}
else
{
 showMessage("Save not usccessful. Try again");
}
```

My question is whether this approach with the `boolean` variable is the optimal way, or could it be carried out in a better way. If my approach is OK, would it be better if the `return` statement would be surrounded with `finally`?

Answer (score 5):

session.getTransaction().wasCommitted(); does return false even if the transaction was committed. Please take a look at

[wasCommitted returns false](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15503976/why-does-transaction-wascommitted-return-false)

what worked for me is

```
// close database connection  
public boolean closeDBConnection() {  
    boolean successful = false;  
    try {  
        session.getTransaction().commit();  
        successful = true;  
    } catch (HibernateException r) {  
    //log exception here  
    } finally {  
        session.close();  
        session = null;  
    }  
    return successful;  
}
```

Answer (score 2):

We can use:

```
session.getTransaction().getStatus() == TransactionStatus.COMMITTED
```

Similarly

```
TransactionStatus.ROLLED_BACK
```

But with hibernate 4 only

Answer (score -3):

you can confirm whether the transaction has committed or not with `session.getTransaction().wasCommitted();` statement. If tx committed it returns TRUE.

Comment: this method no longer exists